# How to keep the original sizes of imported image with Xcode Storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, layout, uiimageview, xcode-storyboard

With Xcode 8.3.3 Storyboard I imported a logo.png file, created a UIImageView in my view (whose sizes are, when created, 240 width and 128 height), selected the logo to be inserted in the UIImageView.

The thing is, the logo is deformed to the UIImageView sizes when this was created, i.e. 240x128, sizes which I've never specified.

I tried to manually resize it, trying to make it look like the original logo.png file, but it is a hard task to do by naked eye.

I want the imported logo in the UIImageView to have the same sizes of the logo.png, horizontally centered and 56 pts distant from top layout guide: the last two I did, with Autolayout and constraints; yet, I could not make the image imported in the UIImageView identical to the logo.png...how could I?

Comment: What contentMode are you using for the imageview?

Comment: Is the UIImageView the only view in the screen ? Set the contentMode to `center`. Otherwise create an aspect ration contraint using the image's original size

Comment: I created an aspect ratio like @nathan suggested, but setting `Aspect Fit` did the trick: after setting that, the image was automatically scaled to its original sizes and setting other Auto Layouts did not modify the ratio of the image. 
Please post your comment as answer so I can upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

Adjust the Content Mode to get your desired result.

[image]